# Is there a way to get any variable from a Crystal class?

Tags: class, crystal-lang

In a Crystal class with some instance vars:

```
class Coordinate
    def initialize(x : Int32, y : Int32)
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end
end
```

In order to access said vars, you'd need to write methods like this:

```
...
    def x
        @x
    end
```

That is fine in this example, but can be very tedious and time consuming if you have lots of vars which you need to access. Is there a way to generally access any variable of a class?

I did think of trying to find an equivalent to ruby's `eval()` but since Crystal is compiled there obviously isn't much to work with.

An ideal solution would do something like this:

```
...
    def get(var)
        @var
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Crystal Standard Library provides macros which simplify the definition of [getter and setter methods](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.10/syntax_and_semantics/methods_and_instance_variables.html#getters-and-setters):

Use `property` for read/write access, or `getter` for read-only access:

```
class Coordinate
    property x
    getter y

    def initialize(x : Int32, y : Int32)
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end
end

point = Coordinate.new 10, 20

point.x = 30

puts point.x
puts point.y
```

```
30
20
```